# MySQL select_expr unexpectedly impacting query execution plan

Tags: mysql, database, performance, sql-execution-plan

I have ran in to an unexpected issue with MySQL (5.6.23 Community Server) – where changing the list of fields in my select statement is changing the query execution plan and having a dramatic impact on the query performance.

I think the best way to demonstrate the problem is by way of example. If I create two simple tables:

```
create table table1 (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  random INT,
  value INT,
  KEY (value)
);

create table table2 (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  table1 INT,
  random INT,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (table1) REFERENCES table1 (id)
);
```

and then populate them with basic data (the procedure I used for doing this is at the bottom of the question) – I can then compare the performance of the following two queries:

```
mysql> select t1.id, t2.id from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id where t1.value = 1 order by t2.id desc limit 1;
+---------+----------+
| id      | id       |
+---------+----------+
| 1109700 | 11097000 |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (1.23 sec)

mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id where t1.value = 1 order by t2.id desc limit 1;
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| id      | random | id       | random |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1109700 | 749465 | 11097000 | 538840 |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (4.06 sec)
```

Note that the only difference between these two queries is the inclusion of the two 'random' fields in the select statement – yet it is over three times slower. Also note that I have cleared the linux disk cache via `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and innodb buffer pool by restarting mysql before executing each query

Here are the query plans for these two queries:

```
mysql> desc select t1.id, t2.id from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id where t1.value = 1 order by t2.id desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref        | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | PRIMARY,value | value  | 5       | const      | 22312 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref  | table1        | table1 | 5       | test.t1.id |     4 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id where t1.value = 1 order by t2.id desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref        | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | PRIMARY,value | value  | 5       | const      | 22312 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref  | table1        | table1 | 5       | test.t1.id |     4 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the inclusion of the random fields in the select statement seems to cause the query plan to drop the use of indexes (that's my reading of the 'Extra' column anyway).

I should point out – that whilst in the example above the performance difference is three fold - on my production database the impact is far more pronounced; at closer to 40 times slower. This is because the size of the tables in production are far greater and the table indexes are generally cached (but the record data is not).

I've considered a work around – once I have the output of the first query - I can run the following:

```
mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id where t1.value = 1 and t2.id = 11097000 order by t2.id desc;
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| id      | random | id       | random |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1109700 | 749465 | 11097000 | 538840 |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

For completeness – I've included the procedure I used to populate the table data (note you might want to alter the value of `rows_to_insert` if you plan to run this yourself – 1,000,000 rows took four hours for me):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE random_fill()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter1, counter2, table1_id, rows_to_insert INT;

    SET counter1 = 0;
    SET rows_to_insert = 1000000;

    label1: LOOP
        SET counter1 = counter1 + 1;

        INSERT INTO table1 ( random, value ) VALUES ( CEIL( RAND() * rows_to_insert ), CEIL( RAND() * 99 ) );
        SET table1_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        SET counter2 = 0;
        label2: LOOP
           SET counter2 = counter2 + 1;

           INSERT INTO table2 ( table1, random ) VALUES (  table1_id, CEIL( RAND() * rows_to_insert ) );
           IF counter2 < 10 THEN
              ITERATE label2;
           END IF;
           LEAVE label2;
        END LOOP label2;

        IF counter1 < rows_to_insert THEN
           ITERATE label1;
        END IF;
        LEAVE label1;
    END LOOP label1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**UPDATE 09/09**

I should point out that I've only included the one column in my example to keep it simple. In my production environment - the table in question has 69 columns. We are also using Hibernate - which will select all 69 columns in its select statement. As a result - a covering index is not practical.

My expectation was for MySQL to recognise that - through the use of the 'limit 1' clause - I only need data from 1 row and therefore it would:

  1. Use the indexed values to find the PRIMARY KEY for this one 1 row; and
  2. Go to the disk to only read the value for this 1 row.

Instead it seems to be scanning the data for every row on disk - making the query particularly expensive (I don't know for sure this is what it is doing - but something is causing a three second delay when I ask for the values of those two additional columns).

I tried the same example described above on PostGres and found it was doing what I had expected from MySQL and was **incredibly** fast (over 200 times faster):

```
#     select  t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    from  table2 t2
    join  table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    where  t1.value = 1
    order by  t2.id desc
    limit  1;

   id   | random |   id    | random 
--------+--------+---------+--------
 999984 | 614113 | 9999840 | 622718
(1 row)

Time: 17.973 ms
```

Here's the query plan from PostGres:

```
# explain select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id where t1.value = 1 order by t2.id desc limit 1;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.86..599.14 rows=1 width=16)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..63819201.12 rows=106672 width=16)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using table2_pkey on table2 t2  (cost=0.43..313745.06 rows=10000175 width=12)
         ->  Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1 t1  (cost=0.42..6.34 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = t2.table1)
               Filter: (value = 1)
(6 rows)

Time: 2.407 ms
```

So you can see it uses the indexes to find the right row and then reads the data for just this one row.

Is there a way I can force MySQL to take the same approach?

Or will I need to put a work around in the code (i.e. get the primary index first and then get Hibernate to fetch this one row)?

---

**UPDATE 2015-09-12**

OK - I think I understand what you are saying. The `Using index` statement means that MySQL is *only* using the index. That it doesn't need to go to the data to get the values for the resultset. In otherwords - `Using index` indicates MySQL is using a covering index (with 'id' - the `PRIMARY KEY` - being implicitly included in the 'value' key).

So actually I was interpreting that wrong. I originally thought that it meant the use of indexes had been abandoned all together.

Here is the result from the `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'` (the output was the same for both queries):

```
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| Handler_commit             | 1      |
| Handler_delete             | 0      |
| Handler_discover           | 0      |
| Handler_external_lock      | 4      |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0      |
| Handler_prepare            | 0      |
| Handler_read_first         | 0      |
| Handler_read_key           | 11158  |
| Handler_read_last          | 0      |
| Handler_read_next          | 122727 |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0      |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 1      |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 111571 |
| Handler_rollback           | 0      |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0      |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0      |
| Handler_update             | 0      |
| Handler_write              | 111570 |
+----------------------------+--------+
18 rows in set (0.25 sec)
```

But thanks to your explanation I think I now have a better understanding of the explain output from MySQL. For the second query it is:

1. Starting with 'table1' and the 'value' key. Using this key it finds all the t1.id values from rows that match the `t1.value = 1` criteria; then it
2. Finds all the 'table2' values that have a 'table1' value in the set returned by step 1. It's taking care of the `t2.table1=t1.id` criteria

So the last bit that needs to be satisfied is the `order by t2.id desc` clause and application of the `limit 1` clause. And it's here that I think MySQL could do better. It's creating a temporary table and then doing a filesort. But it appears to be getting the values for all the rows before making the temporary table. But because the `order by` clause is on a `PRIMARY KEY` - technically it doesn't need to get the data yet. It could satisfy the `order by` clause, then apply the `limit` clause and then fetch the data required to complete the resultset. Effectively this:

**SOLUTION 1 (1.30 sec - a bit faster)**

```
mysql> select t1.id, t2.id
    -> from table2 t2
    -> join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 1
    -> order by t2.id desc
    -> limit 1;
+---------+----------+
| id      | id       |
+---------+----------+
| 1109700 | 11097000 |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (1.29 sec)

mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t2.id = 11097000;
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| id      | random | id       | random |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1109700 | 749465 | 11097000 | 538840 |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

A total of 1.30 sec.

But the most efficient approach is the plan created by PostGres - which is to start with table 2 and move backwards through it until you find your one row that fits the `t2.table1=t1.id` and `t1.value = 1` clause. Effectively this:

**SOLUTION 2 (0.04 sec - the fastest)**

```
mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> straight_join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 1
    -> order by t2.id desc
    -> limit 1;
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| id      | random | id       | random |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1109700 | 749465 | 11097000 | 538840 |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

At the moment - the default behaviour of MySQL and Hibernate produces this:

**SOLUTION 3 (3.82 secs - the slowest)**

```
mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 1
    -> order by t2.id desc
    -> limit 1;
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| id      | random | id       | random |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1109700 | 749465 | 11097000 | 538840 |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (3.82 sec)
```

With Hibernate - I can't use the `straight_join` clause so I don't believe **SOLUTION 2** is an option.

But I can get **SOLUTION 1** by putting in place a work around where I get the `PRIMARY KEY` from table 2 first and then get Hibernate to fetch this one row.

Have I got this analysis right? Is there any other options I've missed?

Just for completeness I've included the MySQL query plan for **SOLUTION 2** (there is no more `Using temporary; Using filesort`):

```
mysql> desc select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> straight_join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 1
    -> order by t2.id desc
    -> limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | index  | table1        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL           |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,value | PRIMARY | 4       | test.t2.table1 |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE 2015-09-14**

Once I better understood the difference between the MySQL and PostGres query plans - I could immediately see a scenario where the MySQL query plan would perform better:

Default MySQL query:

```
mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 111
    -> order by t2.id desc limit 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

`straight_join` MySQL query:

```
mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> straight_join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 111 order by t2.id desc limit 1;
Empty set (6.29 sec)
```

The queries are the same as my original examples - the only difference being that I'm now looking for a `value` of 111 (which isn't in this dataset).

So the PostGres query plan will be faster only if it finds a hit early as it rolls backwards through table2. Which - with my production data - I know will be the case. So **SOLUTION 2** would be ideal but I don't think it is possible via Hiberate.

Here's the output of the JSON explain:

```
mysql> explain format=JSON select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> where t1.value = 1
    -> order by t2.id desc
    -> limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "t1",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY",
              "value"
            ],
            "key": "value",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "value"
            ],
            "key_length": "5",
            "ref": [
              "const"
            ],
            "rows": 22312,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "t2",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "table1"
            ],
            "key": "table1",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "table1"
            ],
            "key_length": "5",
            "ref": [
              "test.t1.id"
            ],
            "rows": 4,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

But unfortunately I don't think it tells us anything new.

I did think of a possible fourth solution - and that was to perform **SOLUTION 1** within a single SQL statement. I came up with this:

**SOLUTION 4 (same speed as SOLUTION 1)**

```
mysql> select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random 
    -> from table2 t2
    -> join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id
    -> join (select it2.id
    ->       from table2 it2
    ->       join table1 it1 on it2.table1=it1.id
    ->       where it1.value = 1
    ->       order by it2.id desc) as temp on t2.id = temp.id
    -> limit 1;
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| id      | random | id       | random |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1109700 | 749465 | 11097000 | 538840 |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (1.24 sec)
```

Here's the explain:

```
mysql> desc select t1.id, t1.random, t2.id, t2.random from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.table1=t1.id join (select it2.id from table2 it2 join table1 it1 on it2.table1=it1.id where it1.value = 1 order by it2.id desc) as temp on t2.id = temp.id limit 1;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref            | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 89248 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t2         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,table1 | PRIMARY | 4       | temp.id        |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | test.t2.table1 |     1 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | it1        | ref    | PRIMARY,value  | value   | 5       | const          | 22312 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | it2        | ref    | table1         | table1  | 5       | test.it1.id    |     4 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It is effectively creating a derived table (derived2) which has all the t2.id's and the order I need them in - and then joining the t1 and t2 tables so I can get the 'random' values. But the good thing about this approach is when MySQL creates the temporary table (during the 4th item of the explain) it is 'Using index' - thus it is quicker than **SOLUTION 3**. But I don't think you can create derived tables in Hibernate so I tried one last solution.

**SOLUTION 5 (same speed as SOLUTION 3)**

```
mysql> select t2.id, t2.random
    -> from table2 t2
    -> where (t2.table1, t2.id) IN (select it1.id, it2.id
    ->                              from table1 it1
    ->                              join table2 it2 on it1.id = it2.table1
    ->                              where it1.value = 1
    ->                              order by t2.id desc)
    -> order by t2.id desc
    -> limit 1;
+----------+--------+
| id       | random |
+----------+--------+
| 11097000 | 538840 |
+----------+--------+
1 row in set (3.37 sec)
```

And the Explain:

```
mysql> desc select t2.id, t2.random from table2 t2 where (t2.table1, t2.id) IN (select it1.id, it2.id from table1 it1 join table2 it2 on it1.id = it2.table1 where it1.value = 1 order by t2.id desc) order by t2.id desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | it1   | ref    | PRIMARY,value  | value   | 5       | const       | 22312 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | it2   | ref    | PRIMARY,table1 | table1  | 5       | test.it1.id |     4 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,table1 | PRIMARY | 4       | test.it2.id |     1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Unfortunately this didn't produce any benefit over **SOLUTION 3**. The difference between this solution and **SOLUTION 4** isn't obvious from the output of the explain plan. The only thing I can think of is that the `order by` is taking place on the derived table in **SOLUTION 4** (which is only indexed values) and only once every value has been fetched for **SOLUTION 5** (including all the non-indexed `random` values).

So my preferred solutions (most preferred listed first) are:

1. SOLUTION 2
2. SOLUTION 4
3. SOLUTION 1

I don't think I can implement **SOLUTION 2** or **SOLUTION 4** when using Hibernate - so that leaves **SOLUTION 1**.

Anything else I should try before I proceed with **SOLUTION 1**?

---

**UPDATE 2015-09-17 - The Conclusion**

OK - I've gone with **SOLUTION 1**.

But thank-you Rick. Your assistance has been invaluable. With my new knowledge I've been able to optimise a number of existing queries.

For anyone who is reading this having ran in to the same problem - here's a summary of the problem and a means for resolution.

The simple yet problematic query being generated by Hibernate was:

```
select tran_.id as id13_1_, tran_.deleted as deleted13_1_, join_item1_.id as id9_0_
from tran tran_
inner join item join_item1_ on tran_.item=join_item1_.id
where join_item1_.itemType=120
order by tran_.id desc
limit 100;
```

Note that I've reduced the number of fields in the select list and changed the table names to make the example easier to read and more relevant.

I have 17,286,852 rows in `tran` and 971,020 in `item` with 105 different item types.

The above query took 20 min 47.32 sec to execute. Way, *way* too long.

The reason it took so long is because of the order MySQL is processing the steps. It would:

1. First use the index on `itemType` within the `item` table to find all the items of the right type (`where itemType=120`)
2. Then use the index on `item` in the `tran` table for the `join` (`join item on tran.item=item.id`)
3. It would then (not sure of order):

   - a) load the data from every column of every row hit so far; and
   - b) sort based on `tran_.id desc`
4. Reduce the resultset based on the `limit 100` clause

Therefore, at step 3a) - it is loading a lot of data that isn't in the final resultset. There are 69 columns in the `tran` table - and prior to applying the `limit` clause - this resultset has 376,652 rows. It's a very expensive and unnecessary IO exercise!

Once I understood this - I recognised that step 3a) should be applied after step 4. I wanted the order of execution to be:

1. First use the index on `itemType` within the `item` table to find all the items of the right type (`where itemType=120`)
2. Then use the index on `item` in the `tran` table
3. Sort based on `tran_.id desc`
4. Reduce the resultset based on the `limit 100` clause
5. Load the data from every column for the remaining 100 rows (avoiding the need to load the other 376,552 rows)

Note that this order can only be achieved if all the fields used from steps 1 to 4 are included in the indexes used by the query plan. In my example they are (with `tran.id` being implicitly included in the `tran.item` index).

To get MySQL to do this - you first want to do steps 1 through 5 with only indexed values in your select list (so your query plan will show `Using index` at each step). For example (only the select clause is changed):

```
select tran_.id as id13_1_
from tran tran_
inner join item join_item1_ on tran_.item=join_item1_.id
where join_item1_.itemType=120
order by tran_.id desc
limit 100;
```

I can then use this resultset as a derived table to feed my original query both:

- the 100 rows I need; and
- their order.

For example:

```
select tran_.id as id13_1_, tran_.deleted as deleted13_1_, join_item1_.id as id9_0_
from tran tran_
inner join item join_item1_ on tran_.item=join_item1_.id
inner join (select tran_.id as id13_1_
            from tran tran_
            inner join item join_item1_ on tran_.item=join_item1_.id
            where join_item1_.itemType=120
            order by tran_.id desc
           ) as ids
limit 100;
```

Be sure to remove the `order by` clause from your outer query. Otherwise MySQL falls back in to its bad habits. The `where` clause is no longer necessary in the outer. The `limit 100` clause can actually be on the inner or outer query.

The query plan for this new query shows the the derived table being created using only index values. It then completes the outer query by starting with `tran_.id` - so it can quickly find and only load the 100 rows.

You might think that I may as well have written the query like so:

```
select tran_.id as id13_1_
from tran tran_ force key (PRIMARY)
straight_join item join_item1_ on tran_.item=join_item1_.id
where join_item1_.itemType=120
order by tran_.id desc
limit 100;
```

And you would be right - this is much quicker. But only when the 100 rows I need are in the top half of the `tran` table. It quickly becomes inferior if, for example, I change the limit clause to `limit 376552, 100` (which took 46 min 11.87 sec to execute).

However - you can't (I don't think) create derived tables in hibernate. You can either:

- a) convert the inner table in to a view (and create an additional entity class); or
- b) run the inner table first and put the resultset in a `in` clause

I went with option b. Here is the Java code that I originally had:

```
result = getCriteria().setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY).setFirstResult(index).setMaxResults(ROW_BUF_SIZE).list();
```

where:

- `getCriteria()` returns a `org.hibernate.Criteria` object (pointing at the root entity) which includes the `join`, `where` and `order by` clauses
- `index` is the first digit of the `limit` clause
- `ROW_BUF_SIZE` is the second digit of the `limit` clause (hardcoded to 100)

I changed it to be:

```
    Criteria crit = getCriteria().setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY).setFirstResult(index).setMaxResults(ROW_BUF_SIZE);
    List<?> ids = crit.setProjection(Property.forName("id")).list();
    crit.setProjection(null).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY);
    if(!ids.isEmpty()) crit.add(Restrictions.in("id", ids)).setFirstResult(0);
    result = crit.list();
```

So lines 1 and 2 produce the inner query and get the resultset. I reuse the same `crit` object - so line 3 just reverts the projection created on line 2. Line 4 will add the new `in` clause (but not if the resultset is empty - as this results in a MySQL exception). Line 5 now gets the same resultset the previous code was getting - but it just gets it a *lot* faster (in 2 seconds vs. the previous 20 min 47.32 sec in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are far more answers to your questions than there is room here.  I'll give you a few clues, plus some references.

"Composite" indexes are often useful.  In particular, `INDEX(last, first)` is better than `INDEX(last), INDEX(first)` when the query says `WHERE last = 'James' AND first = 'Rick'`.

A "covering" index is one in which *all* the columns needed for a `SELECT` are in a single index.  "Inclusion of random fields" moves away from "covering".

In `EXPLAIN` (alias `DESC`), `Using index` is the clue that it could use a covering index.

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly tacked on the end of every secondary key.  In your first example `KEY(value)` is effectively the composite index `KEY(value, id)`.

One thing that sometimes fools people is when they run a query and it is slow, then they run another query (or the same) and it is faster.  The answer is often that the first query was slow because of fetching data from disk; the second found things in RAM (cache), hence was faster (typically 10x).

A common reason for *not* using an obvious index is that the optimizer sees that the index would need to fetch more than 20% of the rows.  It decides, instead, that ignoring the index and blasting through the data is *probably* faster.  (The 20% varies with the phase of the moon.)  Note that an index is a sorted list of pointers to the data.  Scanning the index may be fast, but the reaching over to the data can be costly.

References
[Cookbook on building an INDEX from a SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and
[A bunch more on indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).

The Linux disk cache is(?) irrelevant.  InnoDB caches things in RAM in its "buffer_pool".  (Since you are running 5.6, I am assuming your tables are InnoDB, not MyISAM.  Several things I have said here need modifying for MyISAM.)

Comment: I use composite indexes when I know the where clause (or order by or group by etc) clauses will include them - but not the select. In fact - in my production database I have a customer table with lastname, firstname and I have a composite index that is (lastname, firstname) but I don't include say phone number, or address1, or address2 etc which commonly appears in the select statement. The issue I'm describing is relevant to the fields in the select statement.

Clearing disk cache was just a way to ensure all things were equal when running the query. Otherwise Linux will cache the disk to RAM

Comment: Not if you use `O_DIRECT`; that bypasses the OS caching of disk blocks.

Comment: I didn't know about the O_DIRECT parameter - thanks for that (although for my testing I'm using a VM so I still need to clear the VM host disk cache).

Comment: A covering index would work great in the example I've provided - but in my production environment the table in question has 69 columns. Plus we're using hibernate which wants to select them all - so it's not practical. I'll update my original question to note this.

My expectation however was for MySQL to recognise the 'limit 1' clause and therefore fetch data from the 1 row. I repeated my example in PostGres and that's exactly what it does. I'll post the PostGres results soon.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` can shortcircuit a lot of work _only if_ there is an index completely covering the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, and in the right order.  Since there is a `JOIN`, that is probably impossible.

Comment: If you look at the two MySQL query plans (near the top) - the first has the text 'Using index' under the 'Extra' column - but the second does not. I interpreted that as it using the index for the first query but not for the second. Am I interpreting that wrong? Note that the `FROM`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses are the same for these two queries. The only thing that is different is the fields in the `SELECT` statement. If it is using an index in the first query - then how do I force MySQL to continue that use and avoid the subsequent scanning of the entire table?

Comment: Interpretation is correct.  The second query fetches `random` from both tables, and `random` in not in the indexes, so it cannot be `Using index`.  But...

Comment: The choice to scan the table (or scan the index) is separate.  In both queries, there will be a full scan t1 or t1's index, followed by "Nested Loop Join" into t2's table (via the index) or t2's index only.

Comment: When using a secondary index, it first reaches into (or fully scans) the BTree for the secondary index.  Each node has the `PRIMARY KEY` for the desired row.  If it is not `Using index`, then it reaches into the data via the clustered PK's BTree to get the row.  `Using index` avoids this second BTree lookup, hence is, let's say', twice as fast.

Comment: Back to your first question "Why did it drop the use of the index".  Think, instead, of whether it used one BTree or both BTrees to achieve the goal.  In one case, it scanned all of one BTree; in the other case it scanned all of the other BTree.  In neither case did it use both BTrees for one table.

Comment: Do this to get a better feel for how much "work" it is doing:  `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`.  For a million rows, you will see some numbers that are small multiples of a million.  That multiple will (probably) be the number of scans or probes needed.  Edit your question with the results for further discussion.

Comment: Yes, your understand is clearer now.  The Handler numbers:  I interpret that to mean that it read a million rows, wrote a tmp table of a million rows, then read that back in.  (Plus some smaller stuff.)

Comment: The Handler numbers give no clue of the overhead of the sort other than to suggest that it might be a million rows.  Version 5.6 claims to have an optimization wherein order+limit-1 will short-circuit the sort so that it is Order(n) instead of Order(n*logn).  But I don't know how to get confirmation of that.  You could try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...`.

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` is telling the optimizer "I know better than you do!"  Sometimes you are right.  But sometimes it backfires by preventing using a better query plan.

Comment: Sometimes (sorry about all the "sometimes"), `ANALYZE TABLE` (on both tables) will update the "statistics" so that the optimizer will "do the right thing" without needing the manual `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: I tried `ANALYZE TABLE` with no luck. I've added the output of the `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` is today's edit of the question. I also tried two new solutions - but one doesn't seem possible with Hibernate and the other didn't produce any benefit. So I think I'm going to have to go with **SOLUTION 1**.